# How to start an ACTION_PICK activity with only those contacts which have a mobile phone

Tags: android

I want the user to select a contact to which my application would send a SMS. How do I ensure that when I start an activity with ACTION_PICK intent only those contacts with mobile phone numbers are displayed?

Currently, I'm starting the activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phones.CONTENT_URI);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is not possible. You would need a separate Uri, one that the Phones content provider used to restrict the output to mobile phones only. I do not see that such a Uri exists.

You can still have an activity pick only users with phone numbers, but you will have to write the activity yourself, using a `managedQuery()`.

Comment: I was thinking it could be something to do with CONTENT_FILTER_URI. Any idea what that is used for?

Comment: That looks like it is for use with getting the contact for a specific phone number -- see http://almondmendoza.com/2009/01/30/getting-the-contact-info-when-on-a-number/

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
intent.setType(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

However when used the contact picker will display a list of all the phone numbers with the contacts name above each one so if a contact has multiple numbers you will see multiple entries for that contact

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code, it looks like you can specify the UI.LIST_CONTACTS_WITH_PHONES_ACTION action in the intent to show only contacts with phone numbers. I haven't tried this out though. Also, this action has the same effect as the contact setting "Only contacts with phones"

Comment: Isn't that undocumented - not part of the SDK?

Comment: It is in the SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.UI.html